# Merge 2 sorted linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am new to data structures and I am trying to code some questions for Linked lists.

The question is to merge 2 sorted Linked lists. I had written the following code for it, but when I am returning next of head from my method I am just getting the last value of the merged linked list. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

here is the code snippet:

```cpp
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
            ListNode head = new ListNode();
            ListNode curr = head;
            while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
                if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
                    curr.next = l1;
                    l1 = l1.next;
                }else {
                    curr.next = l2;
                    l2 = l2.next;
                }
            }
            if(l1 != null){
                curr.next = l1;}  
            else if(l2 != null){
                curr.next = l2;}
        return head.next;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing `curr` after adding a value to the next of that current node, so what really is happening is that you keep on adding values to your current's node next.

To demonstrate

1->5->6  list 1

2->3  list 2

```
head = new ListNode(); // dummyNode;
current = head; // i.e dummyNode
```

#### What happens in the loop:

**firstIteration**

dummyNode -> 1

(notice how you don't increment the dummyNode to the 1 here therefore in every iteration the dummyNodes next would be the  replaced)

**secondIteration**

dummyNode -> 2

**thirdIteration**

dummyNode -> 3

(and so on .....)

after all iterations you'll be left with

dummyNode -> 6

so when you return `head.next` you get 6

#### Changes to the code:

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    ListNode head = new ListNode();
    ListNode curr = head;
    while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
            curr.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }else {
            curr.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    if(l1 != null){
        curr.next = l1;
        curr = curr.next;
    }  
    else if(l2 != null){
        curr.next = l2;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return head.next;
}
```